# Is it possible to use animate.css with already translated elements?

Tags: css, css-animations, animate.css

I'm using [Daniel Eden's animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/) on a website. It works great but I'm having problems with elements that already have a `transform:translate()` applied to them.

## **The problem I'm having:**

I have a `div` that's fixed at the bottom of the page, transformed by -50% in the x-direction and a little over -100% in the y-direction to center it:

```css
#resend_activation_div {
  position:fixed;
  top:100%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 10px));
}
```

which looks like this:
[image]

I add `animated fadeOutDown` to the `classList` of the `div` when the X is clicked. I want the element to fade out directly downwards from its position on the page. The problem is, the animation works in the following way ...

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutDown {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
}
```

... so my original transform rule is overwritten and the element fades out in the direction of the blue arrow in the image above.

## **My workaround:**

The only way I've found to overcome this so far is to define a new class which has the translation I want in it and using that in the `classList` instead ...

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutDownWithCentering {
 from {
  opacity:1
 }
 to {
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(-50%, 100%, 0);
  transform:translate3d(-50%, 100%, 0)
 }
}
```

... which works, but it means writing a new rule for every animation for every different transformation I have on my elements!

So my question is: **Is there a smarter way to do this? Can I make css respect my original transformation whilst performing the transformation in the animation rule?**

Comment: For that particular `div`, you can use `left: 0; right: 0; width: 50%; bottom: 10px; margin: 0 auto;` to avoid using a transform. However, you could also wrap your element in a new `div` that will receive the animate.css transform.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @chriskirknielsen. However, does this only work when you specify a width on the element? The div contains different text depending on the context so in the case that it has very little text, I'd prefer it to be just big enough to contain the content, i.e. to not have a `width` set on the element.

Comment: you make your element using two wrapper, one will get your animation and the other one the animate.css

Comment: You can use `!important` to give your css attributes priority, so it won't be overridden by the attributes following. Or in your case with `fixed` position, just use `margin` instead of `transform:translate`

Comment: Does my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61379744/9060223) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Unfortunately, CSS doesn't have the ability to know what `transform` values the elements have previously without being told explicitly. That being said, there is a workaround to your problem: just tell the CSS explicitly the initial `transform` values.

To achieve what you want using pure CSS, we can use the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to perform calculations. Along with `calc`, we will also be using [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to declare the initial transform value **explicitly**. Then, also tell CSS the value of `translateY` (e.g. `30px`) required to do the fade-out animation. As `calc` can be used to operate on the CSS custom properties, we can now calculate the end `translate` value we want (e.g. `translate: 0px calc(var(--initial-transformY) + var(--added-transformY))`). Putting all these operations in a class (e.g. `.fadeOutDown`), we can now simply add this class to any elements you want to fade out.

---

### Solution #1

Here's an example showing how to use the CSS custom properties and `calc` together to achieve what you want. In this example, you can simply add `fadeOutDown` class (without using the `animation` attribute) to the elements you want to fade out. The class will add the `translateY` value by a fixed value of `30px` (you can also use a CSS custom property if you want).

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('.foo')
const bar = document.querySelector('.bar')

bar.addEventListener('click', e => {
  foo.classList.toggle('fadeOutDown')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.foo {
  --initial-transformY: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, var(--initial-transformY));
  /* or for Firefox, you can also use this -> translate: -50% var(--initial-transformY);*/
  transition:
    transform .5s ease,
    opacity .5s ease;
}

.fadeOutDown {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(var(--initial-transformY) + 30px));
  /* or for Firefox, you can also use this -> translate: -50% calc(var(--initial-transformY) + 30px) */
  /* Or you can use a CSS custom property like this (Firefox)
  --fadeOutDown-value: 30px;
  translate: -50% calc(var(--initial-transformY) + var(--fadeOutDown-value)); */
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 16px;
  background: #ad17fd;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Hello there, I am foo</div>
<button class="bar">Click me to move foo</button>
```

Here's an example using the `animation` property. I discourage using this one because the reversed animation is instant (you can make it so that it appears gradually, but it's extra work). Easier to use `transition` and `transform` together (the above approach).

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('.foo')
const bar = document.querySelector('.bar')

bar.addEventListener('click', e => {
  foo.classList.toggle('fadeOutDown')
})
```

```css
@keyframes fadeOutDown {
  from {}
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    translate: var(--initial-transformX) calc(var(--initial-transformY) + 30px);
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.foo {
  --initial-transformX: -50%;
  --initial-transformY: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  translate: var(--initial-transformX) var(--initial-transformY);
}

.fadeOutDown {
  animation: .5s ease 0s fadeOutDown forwards;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #ad17fd;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Hello there, I am foo</div>
<button class="bar">Click me to move foo</button>
```

---

### Solution #2

Or, as suggested by the comments in your question, you can add another wrapper so that you can apply the two transform values.

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('.foo')
const bar = document.querySelector('.bar')

bar.addEventListener('click', e => {
  foo.classList.toggle('fadeOutDown')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  --initial-transformY: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  translate: -50% -10px;
}

.foo {
  width: 100%;
  background: #121212;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: translate .5s ease, opacity .5s ease;
}

.fadeOutDown {
  opacity: 0;
  translate: 0px 30px;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #ad17fd;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="foo">Hello there, I am foo</div>
</div>
<button class="bar">Click me to move foo</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Richard for the answer. I've run your snippets and they work perfectly in firefox, however `foo` appears to only fade out in all three examples (without the downwards movement) in chrome. Do you know what's stopping this from working with chrome?

Comment: @compuphys Ah, it seems like the CSS property `translate` isn't supported in Chrome. You can use `transform: translate(...)` instead. I've edited the first snippet so that it runs well in Chrome too ;-)

Comment: thanks for this. It's a nice use of CSS custom properties.

Comment: @compuphys Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a small trick you can try, although I am quite sure it will work for you. in this type of element by position fixed, not on all.
The problem you are having is because of the transform property used by you, because the transform by animate.css is overwriting your code.

what you can do is don't use transform on your fixed element at all. try something like this and then try to fade it out.

```
`#resend_activation_div {
    position:fixed;
    top:100%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    maergin-left: -(width of your element/2)px; // half of your element.
}`
```